# Find a CFG for $0^n|v| where |v| = n$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

I am looking for a CFG of given language but I can not be sure about the correctness of my CFG.

Given language is $0^n|v|, |v|=n$

I find this CFG which I belive it solves it.

$S -> 0SX$

$X-> 0|1$

I tried some strings and my CFG works well but it seems too simple for this language so maybe I missed some part.

I have two questions.
1) Does my CFG is correct for a given language?

2) How can I prove the correctness of my CFG?

Comment: What do you mean by $0^n|v|$? Did you maybe want to write $0^n\circ v$?

Comment: @MetaColon Like 000101, which means that left part of the string should be all 0's and the right part can be mixed but should be equal length with left part.

Comment: Then your CFG seems fine to me, except for the fact that you forgot to add $\varepsilon$s ($S\longrightarrow 0SX|\varepsilon$), as right now it would never terminate.